# Converting timestamp string to timestamp in Presto - Malform error

Tags: sql, presto, sql-timestamp, malformed

I am trying to convert a timestamp string to timestamp with date_parse, but keep getting an error. Any suggestions? I am working on Presto SQL. I have tried to replace `%H:%f` with `%T` and it still doesn't work.

```
date_parse(sg."@timestamp", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%f')
```

The error message is:

> presto: query failed (200 OK): "USER_ERROR: com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Invalid format: "2017-12-31 08:29:02.12" is malformed at ":02.12""

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need [`date_parse()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) with this format:

```
presto:default> SELECT date_parse('2017-12-31 08:29:02.12', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S.%f');
          _col0
-------------------------
 2017-12-31 08:29:02.120
(1 row)
```